# Error on EF migration - Azure - MySQL on App

Tags: mysql, azure, migration

I'm trying to run all pending migrations on my web app asp.net core 2.1 on Azure using MySQL on app, free tier (always on not enabled) but I receive an error, as in the log file:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '127.0.0.1:54184'"
```

The MySQL package I'm using is `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`, version 2.1.1.
I'm running this code in the `configure` method of the startup class:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SandroDbContext>())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

It seems to get the correct server and port from the environment variable for *MySQL in App*, but not the database name.

UPDATE:
It doesn't work even if I remove the lines of code to apply migrations.
Simply by injecting the `DbContext` I have the same error.
It may be because when the web app starts, the SQL in app isn't yet available.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is the connection string that Azure provides via environment variable. It misses the parameter "Port", because the port is next to the server name, but the connection string is invalid this way. I've made a few lines of code to fix it.

```
        public string FixAzureConnectionString(string connStr)
        {
            string goodConnStr = connStr;
            string portNumber = Regex.Match(goodConnStr, @"(?<=Data Source.+:)\d+")?.Value;
            goodConnStr += ";Port=" + portNumber;
            goodConnStr = goodConnStr.Replace(":" + portNumber, "");
            return goodConnStr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

3 years later but as pointed out by OP, the connection string created by Azure is missing the Port property.

Open the Kudu console and navigate to **c:\home\data\mysql** and open the file **MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini**. Change it from this:

`Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=azure;Password=5$vPWD_#`

To this:

`Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Port=52775;User Id=azure;Password=5$vPWD_#`

In my case, I also added the connection string in the App Service Configuration.